# spring-data-rest-webmvc 2.0.0 - RepositoryRestExporterServlet missing

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-data-rest

I'm trying to create a REST web service with spring-data-rest-webmvc 2.0.0.
I'm following the handbook "Spring in Practice" where you use the version 1.0.0.
In this handbook, it define the exporter servlet in web.xml as below:

```
<web-app ...>
    ...
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>api</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.RepositoryRestExporterServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>api</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/api/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

in version 2.0.0, I can not find the RepositoryRestExporterServlet class.
What dispatcher servlet should I use?
Where I can get some examples?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add

```
 <bean class="org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.config.RepositoryRestMvcConfiguration"/>
```

To your regular `spring-mvc-servlet.xml` config and then you can use both the REST servlet and Spring MVC servlet.

Otherwise, for SDR 2, you should use:

`org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.RepositoryRestDispatcherServlet`

in `web.xml`