# Cannot run Spring Data Rest with Google App Engine (GAE)

Tags: java, spring, google-app-engine, spring-data, spring-data-rest

This is the error that I see when running Spring Data Rest app with appengine:devserver

```
[INFO] java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.RepositoryRestExporterServlet
[INFO]  at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
[INFO]  at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
[INFO]  at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
[INFO]  at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
[INFO]  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:423)
[INFO]  at com.google.appengine.tools.development.IsolatedAppClassLoader.loadClass(IsolatedAppClassLoader.java:216)
[INFO]  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:356)
[INFO]  at org.mortbay.util.Loader.loadClass(Loader.java:91)
[INFO]  at org.mortbay.util.Loader.loadClass(Loader.java:71)
[INFO]  at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.Holder.doStart(Holder.java:73)
[INFO]  at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.doStart(ServletHolder.java:242)
[INFO]  at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:50)
[INFO]  at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.initialize(ServletHandler.java:685)
[INFO]  at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.Context.startContext(Context.java:140)
[INFO]  at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startContext(WebAppContext.java:1250)
[INFO]  at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.doStart(ContextHandler.java:517)
[INFO]  at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart(WebAppContext.java:467)
[INFO]  at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:50)
[INFO]  at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.doStart(HandlerWrapper.java:130)
[INFO]  at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:50)
[INFO]  at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.doStart(HandlerWrapper.java:130)
[INFO]  at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.doStart(Server.java:224)
[INFO]  at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:50)
[INFO]  at com.google.appengine.tools.development.JettyContainerService.startContainer(JettyContainerService.java:254)
[INFO]  at com.google.appengine.tools.development.AbstractContainerService.startup(AbstractContainerService.java:305)
[INFO]  at com.google.appengine.tools.development.AutomaticInstanceHolder.startUp(AutomaticInstanceHolder.java:26)
[INFO]  at com.google.appengine.tools.development.AbstractModule.startup(AbstractModule.java:79)
[INFO]  at com.google.appengine.tools.development.Modules.startup(Modules.java:97)
[INFO]  at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerImpl.doStart(DevAppServerImpl.java:255)
[INFO]  at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerImpl.access$000(DevAppServerImpl.java:47)
[INFO]  at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerImpl$1.run(DevAppServerImpl.java:213)
[INFO]  at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerImpl$1.run(DevAppServerImpl.java:211)
[INFO]  at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
[INFO]  at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerImpl.start(DevAppServerImpl.java:211)
[INFO]  at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerMain$StartAction.apply(DevAppServerMain.java:277)
[INFO]  at com.google.appengine.tools.util.Parser$ParseResult.applyArgs(Parser.java:48)
[INFO]  at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerMain.run(DevAppServerMain.java:219)
[INFO]  at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerMain.main(DevAppServerMain.java:210)
[INFO]
```

Although the dependency is there:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-data-rest-webmvc</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.0.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The version of Spring REST, that you are using does not have RepositoryRestExporterServlet anymore, it was replaced by RepositoryRestDispatcherServlet

[spring-data-rest-webmvc 2.0.0 - RepositoryRestExporterServlet missing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22302593/spring-data-rest-webmvc-2-0-0-repositoryrestexporterservlet-missing)

Here is a change from github
https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-rest/commit/6e4e7da142fde7036bf3d9daa8caa25f8a40b330#diff-ea97fe02024ec0947925b1cf92a34473

Answer (score 0):

Could you ensure that all the Spring JARs are present in the `WEB-INF\lib` folder of your deployed application.

Comment: Hmm... right... I wonder why spring-data-rest jars are not being copied in the WEB-INF\lib folder